# Cross-Domain iframe communication

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe being created on a page, and the page's domain is being explicitly set to 'xyz.com' but the iframe's domain is defaulting to 'dev.xyz.com', which is the actual domain i'm developing for.

The problem is, when I try to access that iframe via iframe.contentWindow.document, it fails due to the difference in domain.

I've tried setting the iframe's src to a file with document.domain = 'xyz.com' but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick...

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you need to set both the iframe's document.domain and the main page's document.domain to the same thing. ([more info here](http://jszen.blogspot.com/2005/03/cross-domain-security-woes.html))

Comment: As a follow up, here is the code that is creating the iframe, and attempting to access it: 

jQuery("body").prepend('<iframe id="jQuery_history" style="display: none;"'+' src="javascript:false;"></iframe>');

var ihistory = jQuery("#jQuery_history")[0];
var iframe = ihistory.contentWindow.document;

Comment: Since you have access to both parent and iframe, I'd recommend the following read: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2010/01/15/backwards-compatible-postmessage/

Comment: Ben Alman has an awesome jquery plug-in that can be used to solve this problem. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: This library supports HTML5 postMessage and legacy browsers with resize+hash https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole (Ben Alman's jQuery Plugin hasn't been touched in 3 years)

Comment: you can also use some handshaking using this library https://github.com/mdx-dev/inception

Answer (score 12):

Page inside iframe:

```
<script>
document.domain = document.domain;
</script>
```

It looks silly, but it works. See "[What does document.domain = document.domain do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do)".

Comment: This dirty hack will interfere, when you'll be having **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** requests, alike CDNs in AJAX loads from JS. Be careful in using it.

Answer (score 8):

After some research, I found this [jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) that makes postMessage backwards-compatible with older browsers using various tricks.

Here is a quick example showing how to send the height of the iframe's body to the parent window:

**On the host (parent) page:**

```
    // executes when a message is received from the iframe, to adjust 
    // the iframe's height
    $.receiveMessage(
        function( event ){
            $( 'my_iframe' ).css({
                height: event.data
            });
    });
   // Please note this function could also verify event.origin and other security-related checks.
```

**On the iframe page:**

```
$(function(){

    // Sends a message to the parent window to tell it the height of the 
    // iframe's body        
    var target = parent.postMessage ? parent : (parent.document.postMessage ? parent.document : undefined);

    $.postMessage(
        $('body').outerHeight( true ) + 'px',
        '*',
        target
    );

});
```

I've tested this on Chrome 13+, Firefox 3.6+, IE7, 8 and 9 on XP and W7, safari on OSX and W7. ;)

Answer (score 0):

As a addition to the reference to the Ben Alman
 plug in I thought I would post this working example. It ]rRelies on an iframe which has a source page containing jquery authentication & data query script which then passes the result to {other domain} parent window using the message plugin.

NB  message plugin will break if using JQ  v9 as JQV9 does not use "browser" referenced  in the plugin

**1st step:**
Add the plugin code to both sending and receiving docs:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

**2nd step:**
Add this to sending doc:

```
   $.postMessage(
$(X).html(),    
'http://DOMAIN [PORT]/FOLDER/SUBFOLDER/RECIEVINGDOCNAME.XXX'   
 )  ;
```

Where X can be a local var containing preformatted json array or other stuff, and the http url here is the address of the receiving document.

**3rd step:**
Add this to receiving doc:

```
    $.receiveMessage(
    function(event){
        alert("event.data: "+event.data);
                $("#testresults").append('<h1>'+event.data+'<h1>');

    },          
    'http://DOMAIN.COM OR SOMETHING'

);
```

Where the http url is the DOMAIN of the sending document.
Good in IE 8, 9, FF16, safari Windows (windows wait x V9 not tested yet), safari x mac thing.

The result is any item you want out of another domain page (that you have access to..).