# javascript document.domain and port number

Tags: javascript, dns

**Prerequisites:**

The browser keeps the domain as a pair ('domain','port') and setting document.domain to its own value (or any other correct one) causes the setter to overwrite port number with null (ok, WTF!?)

See: [What does document.domain = document.domain do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do)

**Question:**

Is it possible to invoke the setter in a way that preserves the port or allows one to set it?

Comment: not in a robust way AFAIK since this is highly dependent on the specific browser/version/implementation... see for example the restrictions Mozilla imposes - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain

Answer (score 4):

No.

If you never set the document.domain it's "special" it knows its never been set, and also includes the port.

Once you set it it's just a simple string, no port, and will only match other frames that have that same string.

A never set document.domain will NOT match a document.domain that was set - even if both look like they are exactly the same thing. It has nothing to do with the port. A changed document.domain will never match one that was not changed, even if it was changed to "itself".

Comment: This is all I know, I just hoped for some weird quirks allowing that. Like the fact that in browsers that render it a .hta document hasn't got some of the cross-domain restrictions.