# extjs form.submit blocked a frame with origin

Tags: extjs, cross-domain, form-submit

In ExtJs I am uploading a file via form.submit.

```
        if (field.up('form').getForm().isValid()) {
        field.up('form').getForm().submit({
            url: ExtApplication4.util.GlobalVar.urlUploadPositionSheet,
            waitMsg: 'Uploading your file...',
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'text/html'
            },
```

Error message

```
{success:false,message:"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:57007" from accessing a cross-origin frame."}
```

I see there's tons of posts about this...
[Extjs fileuplaod - cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627392/extjs-fileuplaod-cross-origin-frame)

But even though I am following it I still cannot return success.

Does anyone know where I would put the

```
response.write('document.domain = "' + params.__domain + '";'); response.write(JSON.stringify({msg: 'Welcome ' + params.name})); response.end('');
```

that is mentioned in the solution.  If that is even the solution.

Comment: Have you tried building the application and trying again? A form will not upload cross-domain, and I've had the same error resolve if built. If the upload url is localhost/.... and you're testing on localhost:57007/... it will fail.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean.  my extjs application will be on a different domain than the webapi which is where I am uploading the file to.  are you saying this is not possible?

Comment: Oh, I see. Ext JS form file upload will fail cross-domain. Searching around a bit I see people opting for ajax request instead, and I've found [this(?)](https://www.guaneri.com/index.php/2015/09/17/cross-domain-extjs-file-uploading/). Though I haven't taken this on myself, so I can't be of much help besides searching around with you... sorry!

Comment: i saw that... doesn't seem to help too much but thanks for searching.

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this and it turns out that:
This solution only work if the two domains

1.belongs to the same parent domain, like http://static.a.com and http://service.a.com

or

2.are with same host name, just different ports, like http://localhost:81 and  http://localhost:82

Comment: This is a comment, not a solution.