# Unable to load iframe in sandbox environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, etherpad

I am trying to load iframe with sandbox enabled in my webpage but it is showing error:

> An error occured while loading the pad
>   Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes.

The code for embedding iframe is:

```
<iframe 
    id="iframe1" 
    name="iframe1" 
    src="http://localhost:9002/p/6dN6dkWRmd" 
    height="700px" width="500px" 
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-top-navigation">
</iframe>
```

In the iframe javascript i found that this code is throwing error:

> if ((!browser.msie) && (!(browser.mozilla && browser.version.indexOf("1.8.") == 0))) {
>                   document.domain = document.domain; // for comet
>                 }

Can someone please explain what this `document.domain` is doing and what should I do to run this iframe in sandbox environment?

**Note:** Without sandbox it is working fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is that you iframe is on localhost, try using another domain, even if it is just pointing back to your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

From ["Document.domain - Web APIs | MDN"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain#setter)

```
Note that setting document.domain to its current value is not a no-op. It still changes the origin. For example, if one page sets
          document.domain = document.domain;
then it will be counted as cross-origin from any other normally-same-origin pages that have not done the same thing.
```

This should let the iframe page be treated as cross domain even if they are on the same domain.

Check CORS (cross origin) and CSRF (cross site request forgery).